# in-app purchases (swf) for ios

Tags: actionscript-3, application-loader

I'm creating a game in starling (as3) and i'm offering extra content through in-app purchases. The in-app purchase is in the form of an .swf file.

Now when i try to upload it using apple's application loader, i cant select the swf files.

It seems i can only pass signed zip files? Is this correct and how would this work for me? 
Isn't there any other way to upload it? Or is there a way to upload swf files after all?

I'm a bit stuck here, so every help is appreciated.

Comment: What do your SWF files contain? Code or just assets? In the first case, you will need to rebuild your app every time you want to add a new item. In the second scenario, you can probably create a ZIP archive of the SWF file and load it that way (although I don't how this works w/ the StoreKit API).

Comment: They do contain code, but as of AIR3.7 that shouldnt be a problem anymore. And i tried to zip them but that isn' working neither

Comment: It should be a problem. If they contain code you have to "strip" them so the ABC is contained into your IPA. Either way, can't you download the SWF file from a server instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the settings of Air for IOS and there should be something that says 'included files'.   Include your SWF there, also include it in the same folder as your FLA.  Import the SWF in your code if you would want to use it, but you shouldn't upload SWFs to Application Loader, only IPAs.